# Why does the general solution of $y'=y$ not covering $y=0?$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It is regarding the ODE $y'=y.$

Usually we try to find its general solution using *separation of variables* as

$\frac{dy}{y}=dx\implies\log y=x+c\implies y=e^{x+c}$ ($c$ being arbitrary constants).

Please tell me why does the general solution does not cover the case $y=0.$

Comment: Note that separation of variables does not always find all possible solutions (as one can see from the derivation of that method). But it often suffices for IVPs because solutions are mostly unique by Picard Lindelöf.

Answer (score 3):

Reason: your method "separation of variables".

If you write $\frac{dy}{y}$, then you should have $y \ne 0$. Furthermore $ \log$ is only defined for positive values.

Comment: Why do we call it a general solution if it is not covering all cases?

Comment: How to find all the functions satisfying this DE?

Answer (score 2):

So the way to get all the solutions is to write this as $y'-y=0$ and treat it as a linear equation with trial solution $y=e^{\alpha x}$ from which we obtain $\alpha=1$.

As a linear equation we know that the solutions are linear combinations of the relevant trial solutions and therefore $y=Ae^x$ is the general form.

Note that the form $y=e^{x+c}$ does not cover solutions with $y\lt 0$ either.

---

Another route which finds a general solution is to take $$z=ye^{-x}$$ then $$z'=y'e^{-x}-ye^{-x}=\text{ [y'=y] }0$$ So $z=A$ is constant and $y=Ae^x$. This can be used to justify the trial solution method, but by coming down to $z'=0$ it reverts to basic theorems in calculus to establish existence and uniqueness.

Separation of variables is a computational convenience requiting care to avoid implicit assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

The general solution of $y'=y$ is : 
$$y(x)=C\:e^x$$ 
any value of $C$.

Especially in case $C=0$ we get $y(x)=0$. So this particular solution isn't forgotten in the above general solution.

Your solution $y=e^{x+c}$ is uncomplete because $e^{x+c}>0$ which forgets the solutions negative or nul.

With you method of solving, at first you should write "The solutions other than $y(x)=0$ ". Then you are allowed to divide by $y$. And at end include the solution $y=0$ into the set of functions found. Also you should write $\ln|y|$ instead of $\ln(y)$ in order to not forget the negative functions. 
Your result will be :
$$y(x)=\begin{cases}
e^ce^x \\
0 \\
-e^ce^x
\end{cases}$$
which can be gathered into $\quad y(x)=C\:e^x$.

Answer (score 0):

In the first step, you divided by $y.$

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when solving ODEs, you are looking for a non-trivial solution; i.e. $y$ that is not identically zero. Note that the trivial solution ($ y = 0$) is quite often a valid solution, but it just isn't interesting from either a mathematical or a practical point of view. Moreover, as others have mentioned, the method breaks down if we do not assume that $y$ is not zero.

Answer (score 0):

$y'=y$ and hence $dy/dx=y$

We need to look at two cases:
When $y=0$ and y$\neq0$

When y=0, the solution is trivially 
$y'=0$. Integration yields $y=A=0$.

Therefore $y=0$ is a solution